# Does this prime generating way generate all the prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I've thought of the following algorithm to find the entire list of prime numbers:

> Take a prime number $p$ to your list.
>
> $1.$ Multiply all the numbers in your list and call the number you get $P$.
>
> $2.$ Add the new primes that divide $P+1$ to your list.
>
> Repeat ad infinitum.

The question is:

> For which $p$ (if any) will this algorithm create a list of all the prime numbers?

Comment: Starting with $p=2$ looks as though $5$ is skipped for a while, along with $11...41$ at least initially

Comment: @abiessu I feel that this whole question is a bit too difficult to ask here, but it'll suffice to answer some part of this question, or a special case, or show that this is an open problem, etc. Anything that is known about something similar to this.

Comment: Is there another starting number apart from $7$ for which $5$ doesn't appear to be skipped initially?

Comment: As an _algorithm_, it's hopelessly, stupendously inefficient. (But the question is a good one.)

Comment: It is apparently known (wikipedia cites Guy and Nowakowski's "Discovering Primes With Euclid" from 1974) that starting with p=2 does not cover all primes.  see  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Mullin_sequence

Comment: @DanUznanski Well, the Euclid-Mullin sequence isn't created by the same algorithm I've shown here. It only takes into account the _least_ prime number that divides $P$. If it were the least 'not in the list' prime divisor, then it'd be a proof, but now it doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Specifically, in related sequences, it says "The sequence constructed by repeatedly appending all factors of one plus the product of the previous numbers is the same as **the sequence of prime factors of Sylvester's sequence**. Like the Euclid–Mullin sequence, this is a non-monotonic sequence of primes, but **it is known *not* to include all primes**." (all emphasis mine)

Comment: @DanUznanski Could you show me where your last claim shows up on the Internet?

Comment: Unfortunately all I have is Wikipedia's cite, which a lot of things seem to point at; there seem to be no places to find the actual content of the article.

Comment: @DanUznanski Wikipedia's cite would suffice.

Comment: It's cite #7, immediately after the passage I quoted above: Guy, Richard; Nowakowski, Richard (1975), "Discovering primes with Euclid", Delta (Waukesha) 5 (2): 49–63, MR 0384675. It links to http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0384675 .

Comment: @DanUznanski Oh, I didn't see the quotation marks on your other comment.

Comment: @abiessu I suspect there's a phenomenon (similar to Mersenne numbers) where due to the paucity of small prime factors, it is extremely rare for these $P + 1$ numbers to admit square factors.  For as long as it holds true that $P + 1$ is squarefree, then the OP's list of primes will exactly match the prime factors of Sylvester's sequence, and therefore will avoid $5$ (that much is very easy to prove).  But good luck actually proving squarefreeness!

Comment: @DanUznanski Heuristics suggest that the Euclid-Mullin sequence should indeed contain all prime numbers.  The primes are pretty well-distributed mod $41$ (the first prime whose inclusion is still open).  There's every reason to expect $41$ to occur within the next $120$ terms; we're just limited by our ability to factor numbers of this size so as to extend the sequence that far.

Comment: @mathh I agree that the current statement of the question is hopelessly intractable (we can say very little about the distribution of prime factors of shifted primorials, which is essential to this question).  I'd suggest changing the question to a Sylvester-like formulation: start with $P_1 = a$, iterate $P_{n+1} = P_n(P_n+1)$.  Is there an $a$ for which every prime $p$ eventually divides some $P_n$?  This eliminates the unpredictable dependence of $P_{n+1}$ on the exact factorization of $P_n$.

Comment: @erickwong my impression of that sentence is that, unlike the straight e-m sequence, this one (with every prime that divides all the sylvester numbers) is known to fail to collect all the primes, but without the cite available I can't say.

Comment: @DanUznanski Ah, then I apologize for misconstruing your claim!  It's very easy to see that the primes dividing the Sylvester sequence fail to collect all the primes (just look at the sequence mod $5$).  The hard part is that we can't be sure that the OP's sequence follows this pattern: if $P+1$ contains repeated primes in its factorization, then they would only appear once in the list.  Hence my suggested reformulation.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A126263 for this sequence starting with 2 (or 3, if you flip the first two terms, or 7 if you rearrange the first three terms, etc.).